# safe_mode problems after upgrade from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 with Plesk 11

Tags: php, php5

I just updated my server (running with Plesk 11) from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 via the dotdeb sources.
Everything was fine except a few things.

1. I had to disable all safe_modes in several vhosts. Plesk has the 'default' option, but I had to set them to 'off'. So I think the 'default' value is 'on'. Is there a way to set the default value to 'off'?  Screenshot: http://s8.postimg.org/mwlaj616d/attachment.jpg
2. Every half hour I get an E-Mail from my server with the subject `Cron <root@hosting> [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime)` and the content `PHP Fatal error: Directive 'safe_mode' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0`. Where can I fix this? I do not have a cron for the root user which runs every half hour in `crontab -l`.
3. Are there other things I have to do after the upgrade?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Switch off safe_mode in service plans and sync service plans with subscriptions.
2. Check all php.ini files for safe_mode = On

Comment: Thanks, I found more safe_modes in **/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini** and **/etc/php5/cli/php.ini**. After removing them, everything is fine now.